# Microsoft Dynamics CRM CrmServiceClient Performance Issue (DisableCrossThread)

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-sdk

We are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 On-Premise on top of that we have a public portal where users are able to query and create some cases.
on high volume of traffic using JMeter (70 Thread for 30Min) we noticed the average request time is 15s per request which is not accepted.

We are using  SDK  (Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.0.68).... CrmServiceClient

After trial and error for many times we were able to tweak the performance and reach an average request time of 4s
by setting this property to **True** (CrmServiceClient.DisableCrossThread).

But that places the requirements of thread safety on us.

how we can create a Pool of thread safety using CrmServiceClient on our web application and how to test it to avoid threading issues.

or if there is any techniques to communicate with CRM to get high response time.

Comment: did you manage to get any improvement on this? we are facing the same issue when using AuthType=OAuth with Dataverse

Comment: Yes,  just use pooling design pattern. Using C# consurrent list let say 100 objects.when u need any connection just pull it.

Comment: thanks. do you have any code example?

Comment: Check code in below link, just create instance passing object type I think ServiceClient... https://gist.github.com/ajamaeen/117d84d8d7d2b7fe85095894c199e802

Comment: Thanks for this, will have a look, much appreciated